# Register to window messages using 'hwnd'

Tags: c#, winapi

Assuming I have a valid hWnd to an active window (it was retrieved using ‘GetForegroundWindow’ or FindWindow, for example), can I register to windows message of this hWnd, from another application, of course? Is there any Win32 API for this, or a built-in C# method?

Example: In my console application I have a hWnd to the ‘Notepad’ window (running in the background). Can I register somehow to messages indicating the ‘Notepad’ window had moved, changed size, minimized, closed, etc.?

Thanks,

***Elad***

Answer (score 2):

You have to inject a DLL into the process that owns the window.  Use SetWindowsHookEx(), WH_CALLWNDPROC hook.  You cannot write such a DLL using the C# language, the process won't have a CLR initialized and ready to run your code.  Native code is required.  Check [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to know about it moving or closing, then check out [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx). You'll have to write a P/Invoke wrapper for this, since there's no equivalent in the .Net API. You can use this without needing to inject a DLL (use the WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT 
flag), so can keep everything in C# (and it also avoids the hassle of having to communicate between a separate DLL and your main process).

You'll likely want the events EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE and EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY. Note that you get these for all HWNDs on the thread you are listening to, so you'll need to filter by HWND in your callback.

Note that when you use WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT, your own code will need to have a message loop running on the thread that calls SetWinEventHook. Also, the notifications that you receive are not delivered *instantly*, but with a slight delay (similar to PostMessage), but that may still be fast enough for your purposes that you can avoid doing an in-proc hook.

You can use the Accessible Event Watcher app (AccEvent) that's part of the Windows SDK to see what messages are available from notepad before you start writing code.